# SQL and php command error

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem running this command which I am trying to enter my ids from two other tables with the third parameter edison_ssid but I am receiving the following key error because of my table key relationships, the key for patientTable is auto increment:

```
[2016-03-29 18:25:58] [23000][1452] Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`iot_pd_testing`.`patientsTable`, CONSTRAINT `fk_patientsTable_doctorsTable1` FOREIGN KEY (`doctorsTable_id_doctorsTable`) REFERENCES `doctorsTable` (`id_doctorsTable`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON )
```

Command:

```
INSERT INTO iot_pd_testing.patientsTable(Users_idUser,doctorsTable_id_doctorsTable,edison_ssid)VALUES ('26',37,'EDISON-9A-88');
```

How can I get around this where I can enter the values with no issues ?

here is my relationships :

[image]

Comment: Um, maybe remove the constraint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to add a patient record with a doctor that doesn't exist. Check your doctor ID and make sure it is a valid doctor or add a doctor with that ID first.